# Parameters in Grapher

Tags: grapher

I am trying to plot a family of similar functions in built-in Grapher. I read that one way to do this is to write one formula for all functions to be plotted and then define the parameter by which the functions differ. For example, typing in "y=sin(ax),a={1,2,3}" should plot sin(x), sin(2x), and sin(3x) simultaneously; however, I got an error message so I am thinking the last updates changed the way to do this; in that case, how do I do that?

Comment: Using the Animator doesn't help?

Comment: No, there's no such option in there

Comment: Running OS X 10.11.5 with Grapher v.2.5(46), I can plot with exactly that expression. It also works to place the parameters for _a_ directly in the expression (_i.e.,_ plotting `y=sin({1,2,3} x)`). What version of OS X and Grapher are you using?

Comment: Well, that's is odd. My computer runs these two versions too. So I opened Grapher to read the error message, then I decided to change the default language in my computer so I could copy and paste the error message; when I inserted as you advised, it worked as expected. Thanks!